# Ubuntu 18.04 cannot install mono

Tags: 18.04, apt, mono

(I've examined the seemingly similar questions I can find and get to know it's not a duplicate..

Error message:

```
Err:1 https://download.mono-project.com/repo/ubuntu stable-bionic/main amd64 libmono-corlib4.5-cil all 6.12.0.122-0xamarin1+ubuntu1804b1
  504  Gateway Timeout [IP: 117.18.232.200 443]
Get:2 https://download.mono-project.com/repo/ubuntu stable-bionic/main amd64 libmono-system-servicemodel-routing4.0-cil all 6.12.0.122-0xamarin1+ubuntu1804b1 [41.6 kB]
Fetched 41.6 kB in 16s (2,555 B/s)                                    
E: Failed to fetch https://download.mono-project.com/repo/ubuntu/pool/main/m/mono/libmono-corlib4.5-cil_6.12.0.122-0xamarin1+ubuntu1804b1_all.deb  504  Gateway Timeout [IP: 117.18.232.200 443]
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

Following operations have been attempted and none of them work.

1. `apt-get update`
2. follow the mono download [instructions](https://www.mono-project.com/download/stable/) for Ubuntu 18.04:

   1. `sudo apt install gnupg ca-certificates`
   2. `sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys 3FA7E0328081BFF6A14DA29AA6A19B38D3D831EF`
   3. `echo "deb https://download.mono-project.com/repo/ubuntu stable-bionic main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mono-official-stable.list
   4. update index
3. install again with `fix-missing`.

OS info:

```
> uname -a
Linux **** 5.4.0-87-generic #98~18.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Wed Sep 22 10:45:04 UTC 2021 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

**EIDT**: I can directly fetch the timeout deb package from the url, but when installing, it said:

```
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libmono-system-servicemodel-routing4.0-cil:
 libmono-system-servicemodel-routing4.0-cil depends on libmono-corlib4.5-cil (>= 4.0.0~alpha1); however:
  Package libmono-corlib4.5-cil is not installed.
 libmono-system-servicemodel-routing4.0-cil depends on libmono-system-configuration4.0-cil (>= 4.0.0~alpha1); however:
  Package libmono-system-configuration4.0-cil is not installed.
 libmono-system-servicemodel-routing4.0-cil depends on libmono-system-runtime-serialization4.0-cil (>= 4.0.0~alpha1); however:
  Package libmono-system-runtime-serialization4.0-cil is not installed.
 libmono-system-servicemodel-routing4.0-cil depends on libmono-system-servicemodel4.0a-cil (>= 3.2.3); however:
  Package libmono-system-servicemodel4.0a-cil is not installed.
 libmono-system-servicemodel-routing4.0-cil depends on libmono-system4.0-cil (>= 4.0.0~alpha1); however:
  Package libmono-system4.0-cil is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package libmono-system-servicemodel-routing4.0-cil (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 libmono-system-servicemodel-routing4.0-cil
```

Comment: It says what happened. It timed out when fetching the archives. Try again later, like in a few hours or tomorrow, and see if it still times out. Their server might just be overloaded or down, causing a timeout

Comment: Thanks. I hope so but it sounds quite rare..

Comment: It might be a real issue, but servers go down occasionally. It happens.

Comment: I agree, a gateway timeout indicates a network error trying to reach the target server.  That IP address is registered to EdgeCast Networks Asia Pacific Network, does that mean anything to you?  Perhaps you need to update your repository locations for apt?

Comment: No worries, that IP is not related to me(just indicates my regions)

Comment: Besides, I can now download and install that package... Seems it's really a network lag. @cocomac is right!